# Magento 2 extension - How to retrieve customer's data after registration

Tags: magento2, event-observer, extensions, registration

I need to **retrieve id** and **email** from the new customer after registration success. I imagine I have to bind the `"customer_register_success"` event, but my attempt is not working:

> etc/frontend/**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="customer_register_success_observer" instance="<Mynamespace>\<Mymodule>\Model\Observer\CustomerRegister" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Model/Observer/**CustomerRegister.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerRegister implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    echo "Customer registered";
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    echo $customer->getName();
    exit;
  }
}
```

> **registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '<Mynamespace_Mymodulename>',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="<Mynamespace_Mymodulename>" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> **Now when a new customer registers himself he sees the error: "We can't save the customer." (though the registration goes well and the new user is saved on the db), plus I don't see any "echo" message and  I don't know. if the error message depends on my changes.**

**How to debug it.**

Comment: Please let me know magento version is 2.3.X?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerRegister implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    echo "Customer registered";
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    echo $customer->getFirstname();
    echo $customer->getLastname();
    exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: The main problem is that I don't even know where that "echo" should be shown. I don't see any result at all except for that error (but I'm sure it depends on my code)

Comment: That echo should be shown at `createPost` action when you register

Comment: I meant where can I visually see the values printed (in the frontend) ?

Comment: once you register as customer, you can see white screen with all the "echo" statement.

Comment: Ok, that is definitely not happening :), I just continue to see the registration form with the error message at the top. I think that the event observer is not even triggered, in fact I'm searching a way to log something in order to understand what it's not working

Comment: can you please updated your question with all the files so that i can check why your observer is not calling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69803/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-frabis).

Answer (score 0):

You need update your namespace:

namespace Mynamespace\Mymodule\Model\Observer

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

Answer (score 0):

Echo is not a way to debug in the observer.

You should create a log file and check if the observer is writing in that log file or not.

e.g
`file_put_conents("/var/www/html/mymagento/var/log/test.log", $customer->getFirstname())`

Use this line instead of echo and check if there is something written in the test.log file. If there is than your observer is working fine.